Matx react side bar expanding when window is shrunk
I'm using Matx react to make a desktop application. When I have the window maximized it looks like this:

But as soon as I try to drag the window it becomes like this:

Can someone tell me where is the setting located to disable this behavior? I have also hidden the button to make the sidebar static since I need it to be dynamic in size if it helps.
I tried to tinker around with some settings but that didn't help.
